# Removing elements from treemap

Tags: java, treemap

i have written a code which takes an array of integer and i am unable to figure out a way to remove the treemap elements which got (false) value.
Any help would be appreciated.
the code is as.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=s.nextInt();
        String[] str=new String[x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            str[i]=s.next();
        }
        TreeMap<Character, Boolean> store=new TreeMap<Character, Boolean>();
        for(int i=0;i<str[0].length();i++)
        {
            store.put(str[0].charAt(i), false);
        }
        for(int i=1;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<str[i].length();j++)
            {
                if(store.containsKey(str[i].charAt(j)))
                {
                    store.put(str[i].charAt(i), true);
                }
            }
                //code for removing elements from treemap with false value.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no efficient way to locate all the `Map` entries having a given value and removing them. You would have to iterate over all the entries in order to do that.

However, you don't have to do it. Just avoid putting them in the `Map` in the first place. Instead of putting the characters of the first `String` with `false` value in the `Map`, put them in a separate `Set`:

```
Map<Character, Boolean> store = new TreeMap<>();
Set<Character> set = new TreeSet<>();
for(int i=0;i<str[0].length();i++)
{
    set.add(str[0].charAt(i));
}
for(int i=1;i<str.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<str[i].length();j++)
    {
        if(set.contains(str[i].charAt(j)))
        {
            store.put(str[i].charAt(i), true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My original answer was incorrect, since I didn't read the code carefully enough. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `TreeMap` and you want to remove all false values, you can achieve that with a oneliner using lambdas in Java 8.

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> !entry.getValue()); // getValue() will return a boolean
```